# Order confirmation template : phtml file for payment method

Tags: magento2

[image]I have a situation in magento2 where i want to apply css to payment method block in order confirmation template.

But when i inspect it i find additional dl and dt and dd tag.

I have no idea where they are coming from .

So please can someone tell me which file does this tags come from

I have attached the image and the code for payment method

ThankYou

[image]

My Phtml Code is:

```
                    <tr>
                            <td width="50%" style="border-bottom:3px solid #999999; word-break:break-all;" valign="top">
                                <table style="padding:0;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-size: 18px; padding-top:20px;"><b>{{trans "PAYMENT  METHOD"}}</b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">{{var payment_html|raw}}</td> 
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                            <td width="50%" style="border-bottom:3px solid #999999; padding: 0px;" valign="top">
                                <table width="200" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding:0;">  
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-size: 18px; padding-top:20px;"><b>{{trans "SHIPPING METHOD"}}</b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}<br>
                                                                       {{if shipping_msg}}
                                                {{var shipping_msg}}
                                            {{/if}}

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>                                       
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            {{/depend}} 
                        </tr>
```

Comment: please add file path in question

Comment: It is the order confirmation template which can be find be backend of magento  at Marketing ->Email template -> order confirmation template

Comment: I  have added one more screenshot of code

Comment: thanks but please add screenshot which provide some class information so we can get easily

Comment: What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think below path provide the Payment html code in order email.

File path : vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/default.phtml

Comment: I tried but it seems it is not the file from which the tags are coming

Answer (score 0):

It will added form the below phtml file:

> \vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\email\items\order\default.phtml

Comment: I tried that but it seems it's not the file from where those tags are coming

Comment: Can you please give full screenshot. which you provide is not identify any class so it will help if you give tag screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this issue. provide the Payment html code in order email.

File path : vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/instructions.phtml